# Submission of Mac App on Store which uses AuthRef

Tags: macos, security

I have a query about submission of Application on Store, that if we ask user for admin password on every launch of app and contain that reference until the user close the app, and perform privilige task whatsoever the need to use the app during that session. So is it against the rule of app store ? Because I can't get any specific rules details about this in documentation.

I know it might be a security issue but still we need to perform some privileged task in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be allowed on the Apple App Store, your app basically needs to be "sandboxed" ([with a few very specific exceptions, not including yours](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129917/is-it-possible-to-submit-not-sandboxed-app-to-the-mac-app-store)).

And according to [Apple's "App Sandbox Design Guide":](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6)

> The following app behaviors are *incompatible* with App Sandbox:
>
> Use of Authorization Services
>
> With App Sandbox, you cannot do work
>   with the functions described in Authorization Services C Reference.

So if you want to be on the app store, you can't do anything priviledged.